# How can i stop my process until the previous step gets over

Tags: java, multithreading, join, installation

I have written a script in java by using which i am executing .exe file to install an application after that i am copying the files generated via installation to the remote location. But the problem is before the installation gets completed the next step for copy pasting files to machine location is happening. Hence resulting in pasting null files as the installation didn't got finished so files are there. How can i stop my process until the previous step gets over. I tried to use thread.sleep(10000) but that is not helping as installation time may vary.

```
public class threadJoin {
public static void main(String s[]){
    Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            File f = new File("C:\\D\\EVProject\\");

            FilenameFilter textFilter = new FilenameFilter() {
            public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
            return name.startsWith("EVProject");
    }
};

File[] files = f.listFiles(textFilter);

for (File file : files) {     

                try {
                    String filexy = file.getCanonicalPath();
                    System.out.print(filexy);
                    Runtime.getRuntime().exec(filexy);
                    //Thread.sleep(10000);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(threadJoin.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
        }


        }
    };
    Runnable r2 = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            String l ="C:\\Program Files\\PD ";
            String m = "C:\\0.0.9.8";
            File srcDir = new File(l);
            File destDir = new File(m);
    try {           
        FileUtils.copyDirectory(srcDir, destDir);
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
        }
    };


    Thread t1= new Thread(r);
    Thread t2 = new Thread(r2);
    t1.start();
    try{
        t1.join();
    }catch(InterruptedException e){          
    }
    t2.start();

}
```

}

[image: this is error what i am getting by using join()]

Comment: Can you show the code?

Comment: How does your program know the installation is complete?

Comment: it is not checking for completion of installation. My program just invokes the .exe file @DanielWiddis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Runtime.exec returns a Process handle. You can use this Process handle to wait for the process to end. The handle also can give you an int value suggesting the process was successful or not but that would require you to test as it may vary based on implementation.

In your case - try below

Process myP = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(filexy); 
int isTrue = myP.waitFor();

See if it helps.

Comment: thnx it worked :) . One more question if i am copy pasting the files from one location to another then in that case also program should not move to next step until pasting is done. Plzzz answer :)

Comment: That should not be an issue if you are using Java APIs to move the files.

Comment: i am using apache-common-io for copying files

Answer (score 0):

Maybe yuu can use join method [join()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/join.html) , something like this:

```
        Runnable task1 = () -> {
            for (int i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++) {
                System.out.println("task1..." + i);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
            }
        };

        Runnable task2 = () -> {
            for (int i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++) {
                System.out.println("task2..." + i);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
            }
        };

        Thread th1 = new Thread(task1);
        Thread th2 = new Thread(task2);

        th1.start();
        try {
            th1.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {}

        th2.start();
```